# Print neovim api-info using python 3

Tags: neovim, neovim-python-client

I get a human readable list of api functions using

```
:new|put =map(api_info().functions, 'v:val.name')
```

in neovim as suggested on https://neovim.io/doc/user/msgpack_rpc.html.

Problem is, this doesn't show the method signatures like the perl example on http://techblog.babyl.ca/entry/neovim-way-to-go.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use Neovim::RPC;
my $rpc = Neovim::RPC->new->api->print_command;
```

yielding

```
...
vim_replace_termcodes ( String str, Boolean from_part, Boolean do_lt, Boolean special ) -> String
...
vim_set_current_line ( String line ) -> void
...
```

But: I don't use perl, I want to use python and want to print a formatted dump of the neovim api as suggested in https://neovim.io/doc/user/msgpack_rpc.html.

```
nvim --api-info | python -c 'import msgpack, sys, yaml; print( yaml.dump(msgpack.unpackb(sys.stdin.read())) )'
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/info/w/sc/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Trying to isolate the error, I did

```
nvim --api-info | python -c 'import sys; print( sys.stdin.read() )'
```

resulting in the same error as above.

I think the reason is me using python 3.4 not python 2.7. How do you correctly code this in python 3.4?

Moreover, there seems to be a discrepancy between the api function and the python implementation, e.g. if you want to access the api function `vim_set_current_line`, you need to write

```
from neovim import attach
v = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')
v.api.set_current_line("zzzz")
```

and not `v.api.vim_set_current_line("zzzz")`.

Is there a way to find out about "pythonic" api-functions (apart from consulting https://github.com/neovim/python-client/tree/master/neovim/api) ?

Comment: This looks like an encoding error, rather than a python version error. What happens if you try `yaml.safe_dump` in place of `yaml.dump`? (Disclaimer, I no absolutely nothing about yaml)

Comment: It results in the same error. I tried to isolate the error (see editing above). It seems you are right and it is an encoding error, but has nothing to do with yaml.

Comment: Closest to the solution of my first question seems to be `nvim --api-info | python -c 'import msgpack, sys; print( msgpack.unpackb(sys.stdin.buffer.read()) )'`, but it is not formatted yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, there's an emphasis on unicode strings.  `sys.stdin` has a `buffer` attribute that lets you get to the underlying byte buffer, but Python 2's `sys.stdin` does not.  If you want something that'll work for both versions, you can use the `-u` command line argument, as well as `getattr()`:

```
nvim --api-info | python -u -c 'import sys,msgpack; print(msgpack.unpackb(getattr(sys.stdin, "buffer", sys.stdin).read()))'
```

The relevant bit is:

```
getattr(sys.stdin, "buffer", sys.stdin).read()
```

If you're more comfortable using Neovim to work with the text, there is also the `api_info()` function in Neovim.

Comment: The `api_info()` function is, as of 2016/06/27, unreleased.  If you're building from git you'll be able to use it.  It will be in the 0.1.5 release.

Comment: typing `:echo api_info()` in neovim yields a dictionary with myriads of characters, but unformatted. The short-hand version of Tommy A, namely  `nvim --api-info | python -c 'import msgpack, sys; print( msgpack.unpackb(sys.stdin.buffer.read()) )'`, has the same result, this time in unformatted python bytecode. `nvim --api-info | python -c 'import msgpack, sys, yaml; print( yaml.dump(msgpack.unpackb(sys.stdin.buffer.read())) )'` is perfectly formatted, but unreadable, as it seems to be some different codec (base64???)

Comment: @Markus The point was to get the information out of the binary format.  It's up to you if you want to format it with `json` or `yaml`.  The base64 encoded text is because `msgpack` created raw bytes and `pyaml` is treating it as binary data.  Pass `encoding="utf8"` to the `msgpack.unpackb()` function if you want it to create unicode strings.

Answer (score -1):

For python 3 use this:

```
nvim --api-info | python -c 'import msgpack, sys, yaml; print( yaml.dump(msgpack.unpackb(sys.stdin.buffer.read(), raw=False)))' | less
```

Comment: Welcome on the site! How does it work?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Your answer has been flagged as low quality because of its length. On this site we encourage user to detail their answer so that reader don't simply copy and paste chunks of code but actually understand what they do. For example as your answer is pretty close from the accepted one it would be useful to point out the differences and explain why one would prefer using your version rather than the other one.